# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl1' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

> I am using state provider in ng-app and in myCtrl1.js ,the error
>           occurred like

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl1' is not a function, got undefined, Below is my code..

> MainApp.js

```
        'use strict';
        var mainApp=angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router']);
        angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
            .state('Emergency Message', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl:'msg/setting.html',
                controller:'myCtrl1'/*This one generates an error which i have explained above..*/
            })
            .state('setting', {
                url: '/setting',
                templateUrl: 'setting/cchk.html',
                controller:'myCtrl'/*this works*/            
            })
            .state('message', {
                url: '/message',
                templateUrl: 'msg/setting.html',
                controller:'myCtrl1'/*same This one also generates an error which i have explained above..   */   
            });
        }]);
```

> Below file in which error occurs

myCtrl1.js

```
        'use strict';
        angular.module('mainApp',[]).controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
        });
```

> Below is my index page
>
> **Index.html**
>
> This is my html page in and it has all the js,css and all file which
>   are required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="mainApp">
            <head
```

this is the script and css files part to include

```
            </head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <a id="a1" ui-sref=".message">Message</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a id="a2" ui-sref=".setting">Setting</a>
                </center>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <div ui-view></div>





            </body> 
        </html>
```

> This all are the files please help me out...

Comment: you should register your controller like this   angular.module('mainApp').controller(...) , similarly in your config you should be doing angular.module('mainApp').config

Comment: where is myCtrl, which works ?

Comment: angular.module('mainApp').controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){});

Comment: yeah, because it has the right syntax. did you make this change for the other myCtrl1 as well ?

Comment: i am hoping you did not forget to include myCtrl1.js

Comment: yes i included and i did same for myCtrl1 angular.module('mainApp').controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){});

Comment: still error ocurrs ,Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl1' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: <body ng-app="mainApp"><center>
    <a id="a1" ui-sref=".message">Message</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a id="a2" ui-sref=".setting">Setting</a>
   </center>
   <br><br><br><br>
   <div ui-view></div> </body>

Comment: please update the html file in the question.

Comment: i have updated file, please check if you get any error in that..

Answer (score 0):

instead of `angular.module('mainApp',[]),controller(...)`

you should be doing this:

```
angular.module('mainApp').controller(...)
```

Same for everywhere else, where you are using angular.module.
You only need to initialize a module once, like you have done :

```
var mainApp=angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router']);
```

after this everywhere you should use

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

so your code should look like:

```
'use strict';
var mainApp=angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router']);
angular.module('mainApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('Emergency Message', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl:'msg/setting.html',
        controller:'myCtrl1'/*This one generates an error which i have explained above..*/
    })
    .state('setting', {
        url: '/setting',
        templateUrl: 'setting/cchk.html',
        controller:'myCtrl'/*this works*/            
    })
    .state('message', {
        url: '/message',
        templateUrl: 'msg/setting.html',
        controller:'myCtrl1'/*same This one also generates an error which i have explained above..   */   
    });
}]);
```

and:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mainApp').controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
});
```

Comment: i tried it but it gave me an error like angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mainApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: did you change your config to angular.module('myApp').config

Answer (score 0):

you should not define depndancies again

```
angular.module('mainApp').controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
});
```

Comment: you can remove this refrence  var mainApp= 

or instead use  mainApp.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
});

Answer (score 0):

**My problem has been solved, I was facing this problem because when i was attaching my script files, so the sequence was incorrect therefore i was facing this problem.**

Comment: Thanks  @gourav and Abdou Telb